# How to handle camera permissions for tests in mac mojave?

Tags: c++, macos, camera, macos-mojave

I have several legacy unit tests that access the camera in C++ via an external module that handles the camera itself. With Mac mojave the camera permission request opens and the unit tests will fail due to timeout. How can I either automatically allow camera access or deactivate these permission requests altogether?

Note that I can't change the test code that actually accesses the camera. It is a third party module.

Edit: I should probably have called it integration test not unit test

Comment: Not sure if it's going to work or not but you could give a try. Give camera access to "Terminal" under System Preference->Security & Privacy->Privacy and always launch your test app from the the terminal.

Comment: @SolidMercury Sounds like a good idea. I will give it a try. Although I can't add it via the UI it might add itself after asking for permissions once.

Comment: @SolidMercury could you add this as answer so I can accept it? I tested it and in most cases this works except in some tests that run via an external testing framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit testing should not have any I/O calls like File I/O, Network I/O or any device I/O like camera in your case. Unit tests are meant to be fast and should be able to run thousands of test cases in seconds.

Solution is to refactor the calls to your third party module which accesses camera using interface so that, you can do dependency injection with the mocked implementation and control the call sequence and return values.

You can create your own mock implementations or use [google mock](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md) like frameworks with which you can easily get tons of functionalities which are required when you mock functions.

---

Give camera access to "Terminal" under System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy and always launch your test app from the the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have probably called it an integration test not unit test. It isn't designed be me and really needs to access the IO because that is exactly what it tests.